# How to deal with node_modules in PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, ide, phpstorm

I have been setting up my development environment for my `Laravel/AngularJS` project. My IDE is [JetBrains PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). I am wondering what are the best practices for configuring the IDE to deal with the `node_modules` (or `bower_components` or `vendor` for my PHP) folder, so that:

1. It is not included in the `code inspection` as far as the modules' internal code is concerned.
2. It is included in the `code inspection` as far as references in my own code to the modules is concerned.
3. It is included in `Autocomplete` or `Code Navigation` (Ctrl+click on methods)

To make it more clear: I want to be able to Ctrl+click on methods of my node modules and be redirected to the source code of these modules. I also want to be warned if I write a node module method wrong, or if it does not exist. Also autocomplete a method, when I press Ctrl+Space. ***But I don't want the internal code of my node modules to be included in code inspection***, because it takes a lot of time to inspect all the modules, and they are supposed to be ok, so I don't need to inspect them.

---

I already tried two solutions:

- Marking the folders as excluded: This does not work because the folders are totally excluded from the project and redirection and inspection does not work at all
- Creating a specific `Scope` (in PhpStorm Settings), that includes all files except the `node_modules` folder, to use when I manually run `Code Inspection`: It is impossible to exclude the `node_modules` folder, because my IDE recognizes it as a module "I think" (it has [webapp] next to it in the Project explorer). I could however exclude `bower_components` and `vendor`.

**Regardless my tries, what is the best way to deal with it?**

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_libraries_examples_node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's mentioned in [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_libraries_examples_node_modules), PhpStorm auto-excludes `node_modules` folder from indexing for better performance, adding the direct dependencies listed in `package.json` to [javascript libraries](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/) for completion, etc. So the best way to handle `node_modules` is relying on the IDE default procedures